# How to restrict decimal values in openbravoerp

Tags: openbravo

```
If user is entering 678.98 then it should display only 678 in one of the field of a window.
```

I have declare that field as numeric in database and number type reference in tables and columns in openbravo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.floor()`

```
import java.lang.Math;
...
value = 678.98;

roundeddown = Math.floor(value); // roundeddown == 678
```

See also [this page](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/POS_-_Round_to_nearest_5_cents) about another rounding example.

---

Working directly with PostgreSql, use the `floor()` function

To insert data

```
INSERT INTO table ... VALUES( floor(678.98) ) ...
```

To select data

```
SELECT floor( field ) FROM table WHERE ....
```

Comment: I don't want to round the value as it will give me 679 by rounding.In database field/column is of numeric type which i fetched in tables and columns and used Amount as a reference Type so what i want is when user   enters 678.89 it should save as 678.I don't want to go into java or to create a trigger.

Comment: Is there any easy way ?

Comment: `Math.floor()` rounds *down*, so 678.xx is rounded down to 678. What is the DBMS? MySQL?

Comment: Postgresql.I don't want to go in coding stuff what i expect is that is there any type or reference in openbravo.

Answer (score 0):

Set Integer type reference in tables and columns in openbravo.